# Windows batch script for restarting services in a remote desktop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to restart the services in a remote desktop.

1. I need to stop the service.
2. Check the service state.. If not stopped
   then kill the service.
3. start the service again.

I need windows batch script do the above activity in a remote server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] and understand that this site isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can start/stop with `net start <service>` or `net stop <service>` [net documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html)
To check if service is still running use `net start` 
To kill the service use `taskkill /F /IM <processname.exe> /T`
[taskkill documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

Be advised that you can restart the service after crash using the service GUI. Maybe your batch is not needed at all...